# Is it possible to annotate JavaScript for the Closure Compiler adding @language ECMASCRIPT5?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I need to minificate some code using Google Compiler compiler.jar as part of a build process.

I have notice that by default the compiler is set to ES3 when I need instead setting the language to ES5.

At the moment I am trying to annotate my source code in order to fore ES5 using the following scripts.

Unfortunately `@language` is being ignored.

My question:

- Is it possible to enforce `@language ECMASCRIPT5` in code annotation directily in JS source code?

---

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
    // @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
    // @language ECMASCRIPT5
    // ==/ClosureCompiler==


    define([
        'dojo/_base/declare',
        'dojo/topic'
    ], function (declare, topic) {
        'use strict';
        return declare('Message', null, {

            _test: 'default',
            get test() {
                return this._test;
            },
            set test(value) {
                this._test = value;
            },


            constructor: function (options) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No language is not determined by annotations - but by compiler options (flags).

```
java -jar compiler.jar -O=SIMPLE --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5
```

I realize that the web service uses special annotations - but they are part of the special comment block at the top of the file. This is a special case and not used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, unfortunately I am facing some issue when passing the flag from a .bat file, I would really appreciate if you could have some time for reading my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933183/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-javascript-jscomp-sourcefile  once again thanks for your help and expertises

Comment: I saw your other question, but I don't know the answer. The windows command shell is a strange thing. I'm concentrating on build tools which use nodejs to call the compiler as they work on Windows.

Comment: I definitely I agree with your regarding the command shell :). Anyway thanks for your time and support.