# java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.google,javascript.jscomp.SourceFile

Tags: java, batch-file, google-closure-compiler

I need to call Closure Compiler from a .bat file passing a flag `language_in=ECMASCRIPT5` I am using the following script but I receive an error

```
java.lang.classnotfoundexception: com.google,javascript.jscomp.SourceFile
```

I would like to know:

- When I omit the flag code compile fine, so am I passing correctly the flag?
- Could you provide me more information about this error?

---

```
java -Xms256m -Xmx256m  -cp "%~dp0../shrinksafe/js.jar";"%~dp0../closureCompiler/compiler.jar --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5";"%~dp0../shrinksafe/shrinksafe.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main  "%~dp0../../dojo/dojo.js" baseUrl="%~dp0../../dojo" load=build %*
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html):

> (ClassNotFoundException) Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
>
> - The forName method in class Class.
> - The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
> - The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

What I think it's happening, due to the fact the code works when you omit the flag, is that the variable `ECMASCRIPT5` is defined inside the compiler.jar, which you might not be including in the classpath.

You could try placing compiler.jar to your WEB-INF/lib in order for it to be deployed with your application and so on accessible when executed.

Comment: thanks for your time on this. I am trying to pass a flag to the compiler.jar --language_in=ECMASCRIPT5 but I believe the issue is that I am not passing the flag properly in the .bat file. Are you able to review my .bat sintax.... anyway I will investigate also your option too. thanks

Comment: No problem mate! What about trying to set the language as an annotation, instead of passing it as a parameter through the batch file? [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Additional-Webservice-Options) you've got some documentation which might come in quite handy!

Comment: interesting, but this are option for the webservice, instead I need to pass it to the compiler.jar on my local machine.. so  I probability need the flag in the .bat

Comment: Hm.. Is the class mentioned `com.google,javascript.jscomp.SourceFile` in the classpath of your project?

Comment: not sure how to find this. could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can find more info about setting your classpath or knowing what's inside of it in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)! hope this helps :)